# JavaScript scope error, variables undefined

Tags: javascript, scope

Please look at this code:

```
<script>
var mygrid;
function lock(){
    for (var i=1; i<15; i++)
    {
        var cur_row=i + "";
            mygrid.lockRow(cur_row,true);
            mygrid.setRowColor(i,"#E5E5E5");
    }
}
function doInitGrid(){
mygrid = new SomeClass;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="doInitGrid()" dir=rtl>
<div id="mygrid_container" style="width:905px;height:550px;"></div>
<script>lock();</script>
  <button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>  
  <button onclick="removeRow()">Remove Row</button>
  <button onclick="lock()">lock Row</button>
</body>
```

Why when I run lock function (Without the button), my var is undefined, and when I click on the button everything is ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a timing issue, not a scope issue.

You call `doInitGrid()` only `onload` so it won't assign a value to `mygrid` until after the document has finished loading.

When you call `lock()` inline, you do so *as the document loads*.

Presumably you have waited until the document has finished loading before clicking on the button.

Comment: So how can I call lock at the correct timing? is there any solution?

Comment: Move to call to just after you make the assignment in the onload event handler.

Comment: But i have a problem that only after i called   <div id="mygrid_container" style="width:905px;height:550px;"></div>
  I can do a lock, So I need the function to be called after the div is exist..

Comment: Which it will if you do what I said.

Answer (score 0):

If by "my var is undefined" you mean that the variable `mygrid` is undefined, that's because you initialise it inside the function `doInitGrid()` which is not called until onload of the page. The onload event happens after the whole page has finished loading. Other inline script runs when the browser encounters it as it parses the document.

Answer (score 0):

Quentin has answered your question, But I'd like to add that it would be better to clean up your code a bit. Something like this.

```
<script>

function lock(mygrid){ //pass in the grid var
    for (var i=1; i<15; i++)
    {
        var cur_row=i + "";
            mygrid.lockRow(cur_row,true);
            mygrid.setRowColor(i,"#E5E5E5");
    }
}

function getInitGrid(){
   //some initialization code here maybe. Otherwise just take this out
   return new SomeClass;//return an instance
}

var mygrid = getInitGrid();

//and then pass in the mygrid variable wherever you call lock

lock(mygrid);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure when you have called the lock function without clicking button. But it appears that that the doInitGrid function was not executed when you have executed the lock function. The below code may work

```
function lock(){ 
    if(!mygrid){
      doInitGrid();
    }
    for (var i=1; i<15; i++) 
    { 
        var cur_row=i + ""; 
        mygrid.lockRow(cur_row,true); 
        mygrid.setRowColor(i,"#E5E5E5"); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `load()` before the document gets loaded completely. So your variable is not assigned as `doInitgrid` is not yet called.(it gets called only after document is fully loaded)

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating `mygrid` inside the function `doInitGrid()` which is called only on onload. But your script statement `<script>lock();</script>` executes before the page is loaded as it is part of the page HTML. When this script block executes, the value of mygrid is `undefined` which is the default value set by JS for all variables declared without an initial value.

If you want to call lock() when the page loads up, call it on onload after the call to doInitGrid() like this:

```
<body onload="doInitGrid(); lock();" dir=rtl>
```

Comment: But i have a problem that only after i called <div id="mygrid_container" style="width:905px;height:550px;"></div> I can do a lock, So I need the function to be called after the div is exist.

Comment: Onload will be triggered only after all the elements in your HTML are loaded. So it is safe to call lock() in your onload, since the div you are mentioning is guaranteed to be loaded by then.